# Retrieving RDLC report byte [] in a .cs class and not in aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report, rdlc

I have an aspx.cs page

And in it I have an RDLC report, so I retrieve byte [] from that report and transform it into base 64 and return it to my front end.

Now I want to create a method, in a .cs class, where it is possible to point to this report, and retrieve that same byte [].
Is it possible to do that ?

my page aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["param1"].DefaultValue = "1";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["param2"].DefaultValue = "100";

    ReportDataSource datasource1 = new ReportDataSource("ds_ops", SqlDataSource1);

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1);

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamIds;
    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    string encoding = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;

    byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

    string Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write("data:application/pdf;base64," + Base64);
    Response.End();
       
}
```

The method I'm trying to do to access the above report and retrieve the byte [] em .cs

```
 public void getRelatorio()
        {
            ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();

            SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();

            sqlDataSource.SelectParameters["param1"].DefaultValue = "";
            sqlDataSource.SelectParameters["param2"].DefaultValue = "";

            ReportDataSource datasource1 = new ReportDataSource("ds_ops", sqlDataSource);

            report.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1);

            /**/
            
        }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to mention the problem with your attempt so far. An aspx.cs file is no different to a normal .cs file

Comment: But how can I configure my reportviewer and datasource components, so that they can render the report?